# Open a Bootstrap Modal with a PHP Variable without site reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

On my project website you can report posts by clicking on a report button. If you do this, a bootstrap modal will pop up, where you have to choose a reason and also have the chance to comment on this. 
 
The problem is, that the site reloads after clicking on the button because the modal needs the file name, in order to put it in the mysql databases.
Enough describing! Here it is:
( Just for you: 'Melden' is german for reporting :) )

```
echo "<a href='download.php?action=melden&name=$row[Name]' class='btn btn-warning'>Melden</a><p>   </p>";
```

So after clicking on the button, the site reloads and calls the action 'melden' with the get variable of the file name.

```
if($_GET['action'] == "melden") {
if(isset($_GET['name'])){


  $name = $_GET["name"];
```

Then the site gets the action, saves the GET-Variable and opens the modal. After the user entered a reason and has commented on this incident, he has to press 'send', in order to send the report.

So the PHP site waits for the press of the 'send' button and writes the whole report into the mysql database

```
if (isset($_POST["send3"])) {
  if(isset($_POST['dateititel']) and isset($_POST['grund'])){

      $grund = $_POST['grund'];
      $dateititel = $_POST['dateititel'];
       $kommentar = nl2br($_POST['kommentar']);
```

All works like a charm, but I want a method to avoid the reloading of the page. Is it possible that the modals just shows by pressing the button( WITH THE VARIABLE OF THE FILE NAME)?
This would be perfect!

Thanks in advance!
~Max

Comment: You'll want to look into AJAX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid page reloading when sending information to your server, I would suggest [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). [Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) makes sending data to the server very simple.

Here's a short example how it would work.

```js
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```

Here we're sending a name and location to the server in [json](http://json.org/), now in php you would [decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) the Json do what you need to with the decoded data and send back corresponding data (in json format) to the client.